# Zabbix Server Connection to Database failed (ERROR Z3001 [1045]

Tags: mysql, linux, debian, zabbix, mysql-error-1045

I got a Problem with my Zabbix Server.
He was running the days ago, and then the dashboard shows up:
Zabbix Server is running --> Value NO
And: Zabbix server is not running the information displayed may not be current
I didnt change some configs in the past.

Then I looked in the Zabbix Server Log File in: `/var/log/zabbix/zabbix_server.log`
And the Error shows up:

```
 15909:20201011:000020.063 [Z3001] connection to database 'zabbix' failed: [1045] Access denied for user 'zabbix'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
 15909:20201011:000020.063 database is down: reconnecting in 10 seconds
```

I already checked the Zabbix Config File in: `/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf`
DBName, DBUser, DBPassword are all correct

Can someone tell me why the Error shows "(using password: NO)"?
Usually it means that no password was entered for the login?

Comment: Maybe the Logs are not the actual last Informations

Here is the Output of the Command:
systemctl status zabbix-server.service

● zabbix-server.service - Zabbix Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/zabbix-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-10-15 10:53:28 CEST; 8s ago
  Process: 1719 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/zabbix_server -c $CONFFILE (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1723 ExecStop=/bin/kill -SIGTERM $MAINPID (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1721 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM SOLVED

Solution: I was adding an HP Switch IN THE PAST with the HP Enterprise Switch Template.
When the SNMP Discover was finished, there wore more than 2000 Items.
So it was a Stackoverflow :D

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you have no spaces before or after the PASSWORD line, and that it matches exactly with the following 2 files:

```
nano /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
### Option: DBPassword
#       Database password.
#       Comment this line if no password is used.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
DBPassword=Ex4mmpleT3st!
#
#
```

AND:

```
nano /etc/zabbix/web/zabbix.conf.php
$DB['PASSWORD']                 = 'Ex4mmpleT3st!';
```

Verify by checking the RESTARTING and checking the log:

```
service zabbix-server restart
 cat /var/log/zabbix/zabbix_server.log
```