# Z3001 connection to database 'zabbix' failed: 1045 Access denied for user 'zabbix'@'localhost'

Tags: zabbix

like the title says, I can´t connect to Database with Zabbix. I´ve added some HP Enterprise Switches a few days ago. I´ve the exact same problem like discribed in this thread [Zabbix Server Connection to Database failed (ERROR Z3001 [1045]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64366890/zabbix-server-connection-to-database-failed-error-z3001-1045).

but I don´t know how to solve it.

I can log into the database with >mysql -u zabbix -p MyPW

All Credentials in the zabbix_config are the same I use for login.

Comment: Do you access from the same server?

Comment: yes, the database and the server are on the same machine

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution.

modify the cachsize in /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf to 1G or 2G, it depends on how much items you have active. After that restart the service zabbix-server.service.